confluent-go : how to get topic configs using admin client?
Is there a way to get all the topic configurations like retention.ms, min.isr, etc. using the Confluent-go Admin API ?
i.e. to generate output similar to the below which I get when I use the confluent java tool kafka-topics

[appuser@kafka1 ~]$ kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic test-topic
Topic: test-topic       TopicId: lZ-UAHvXSRiKV_dLLXaauw PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: confluent.placement.constraints={"version":1,"replicas":[{"count":2,"constraints":{"rack":"site1"}}],"observers":[{"count":1,"constraints":{"rack":"site2"}}]},retention.ms=172800000
        Topic: test-topic       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2        Offline:        Observers: 3


I tried using the Confluent Go API, but could not find anything in the returned metadata to be able to list all the configurations of the topic
Is there a way to get the Observers and Offline replica count using the Admin API ?

Answering my own question related to getting the topics config using Confluent-Go.
One can use the adminClient method DescribeConfigs to get the topic level config.
I still am not able to figure out how to list observer replicas. Maybe I will raise a separate question for better tracking.
